# Как увеличить размер изображения после прохождения через нейронную сеть?

Tags: python, машинное-обучение, нейронные-сети, tensorflow, распознавание

я написал простенькую нейронную сеть по распознаванию Keypoints на лице

на вход я сую 96x96 изображение и получаю координаты точек лица. Итак вопрос, а как мне теперь подать изображение например 1280х720 и получить точки?
Ведь нейронная сеть получит координаты на размере 96x96 и непонятно как их увеличить. Может быть метод какой-то есть?
Ниже пример того, что я получаю

```
model.load_weights(tf.train.latest_checkpoint(checkpoint_dir))
idx = 6
test_imgs, y = process_img(test_df['Image'])
predictions = model.predict(test_imgs)
plt.imshow(test_imgs[idx].reshape(96, 96), cmap='gray')
print(predictions[idx][0::2])
plt.scatter(predictions[idx][0::2], predictions[idx][1::2], c='red', marker='.')
plt.show()
```

[image: Пример того, как выглядит вывод нейронной сети]

Comment: если тренировал 96*96 то на 1280 будет море ошибок. формат должен быть един

Comment: То есть я изначально неправильно сделал? и надо обучать на данных, которые ближе к реальным?

Comment: @andrey - 'надо обучать на данных, которые ближе к реальным' -  это для вас открытия? Т.е. вы не прочитали ни одной книжки  по НС и даже не посмотрели ни одного видеоурока?

Comment: вы не так прочитали. Я имел в виду, что данные надо в полном размере подавать ? Без сжатия ?